# How do I make images in an inline list scale down to keep the list inline as the div changes size?

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4, html-lists, responsive-images

I have an inline list of social media icons in the header of a website done in Bootstrap 4. As the screen size changes, scaling down, the image icons stay inline until their div gets to 1112px then they start line breaking. Once the div reaches 414px they return to inline and look nice. I've tried setting the list items to specific width and height then creating an image class for max-width: 100% and height: auto but that didn't work. Using the Bootstrap native "list-inline" and "list-inline-item" classes also didn't work.

CSS

```
.col-sm.scl {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center; 
}
.col-sm.scl ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
}

.col-sm.scl ul li {
width: 40px;
height: 41px;
display: inline;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">

<!-- Social Icons -->
<div class="col-sm scl">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/facebook.png" class="socialitems" alt="Facebook   Icon"></li>
<li><img src="images/twitter.png" class="socialitems" alt="Twitter Icon"></li>
<li><img src="images/linkedin.png" class="socialitems" alt="Linkedin Icon"></li>
<li><img src="images/youtube.png" class="socialitems" alt="Youtube Icon"></li>
<li><img src="images/email.png" class="socialitems" alt="Email Icon">.  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Social Icons END -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code I have edited the list to be `inline-block`. You may need to adjust the width of each menu `li` to get the desired look.

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
#myFooter .second-bar {
    background-color: #33373e;
}

#myFooter .second-bar a {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #9fa3a9;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    line-height: 68px;
}

#myFooter .second-bar a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00aced;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #myFooter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #myFooter .info {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="myFooter">
  <div class="second-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
          <h2 class="logo"><a href="#"> LOGO </a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 center">
          <p style="color: #fff; line-height: 68px;">More Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="social-icons center">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A big improvement overall but the menu still begins to line break around the 1100px point when downsizing. Once it reaches mobile size it looks great. I'm missing something in there to keep the menu together and get those icons to shrink to fit. Just for clarification, there are two cols beside the social column. One of those has an image in it. The only styling I did on it was to set the max-width to 100% and it does just perfect. It shrinks right along with the column. The social media icons will not shrink and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It seems too obvious ...

Comment: That's it!! Manually adding that breakpoint in there did the trick. Thank you so much for the help!!